# Javascript: I am having trouble ordering a random string into alphabetical order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that takes in a random string and returns them in alphabetical order. Can you please look at my code and suggest how I can fix it? I'd like to maintain the spirit of my code as I believe I am close. Big thanks!

```
var orderInTheCourt = function(str){
  var smallestNumber = 0;
  var newOrder = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(String.charCodeAt(str[i]) < smallestNumber){
      smallestNumber += str[i];
      newOrder.unshift(str[i]);
  } else{
      smallestNumber += str[i];
      newOrder.push(str[i]);
    }
  return newOrder.join(''); 
  }
}
orderInTheCourt('zyon');
```

Comment: why not just use `sort` ?

Comment: And `String.charCodeAt()`? Probably you should be using `str.charCodeAt()`

Comment: Oh man, I had no idea of the sort method, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function order (str) {
    return str.split('').sort().join('');
}
```

It splits the string into an array of chars, sort it and join it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string into an Array (using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  Then finally [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) your array back into a string:

```
str.split("").sort().join("");
```